# Jeditable received no data

Tags: playframework, jeditable

I'm new to Play framework 2.1.

I would like to use this plugins : http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable
In my controller, i don't recieve post data (id and newvalue).
How i can retrieve them ?

Here is my code :

views :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('role').editable('@controllers.serveur.routes.Serveurs.editServeur');
});
</script>
<a href="#" id="role">test</a>
```

routes :

```
POST  /serveurs/liveEdit   controllers.serveur.Serveurs.editServeur
```

controllers :

```
public static Result editServeur(){
     Logger.debug(form().bindFromRequest().toString());
     return ok("nice");
}
```

result of the logger.debug :

[debug] application - Form(of=class play.data.DynamicForm$Dynamic, data={}, value=Some(Form.Dynamic({})), errors={})

I have no error in my Javascript